# Bluehost, Best way to run server

Tags: c#, php, bluehost

I have Bluehost account and the way I connect to the MySQL database and handle requests from remote devices is to use PHP scripts. I was wondering if I could run my server using C# instead of writing PHP scripts.

Comment: On a bluehost Linux shared  account? Nope. You would have to rent a dedicated server or shared hosting package with Microsoft technology

Comment: @Pekka, there are plenty of shared hosting providers for ASP.Net--no need for a dedicated server.

Comment: @Iceman yeah, that was carelessly worded. Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like Bluehost provides any support for C#. If you want to program web sites in C#, you need to look for a company that offers [ASP.Net hosting](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+hosting).